# GCC Undefined Behavior Sanitizer seems to think inf/inf is not undefined behavior. Why?

Tags: gcc, undefined-behavior

I thought inf/inf is considered undefined, as in this example below:

```
#include <math.h>
#include <stdio.h>
double square(double x){return x*x;}

int main(){
  double x = 2.9e200;
  printf ("x*x=%g\n", square(x)/square(x));
  return 0;
}
```

However, the undefined behavior sanitizer does not see this as an undefined behavior. Where do I misunderstand?

```
 % gcc -fsanitize=undefined hello.c && ./a.out
x*x=nan
```

Comment: I would guess it's "undefined" in the mathematical sense, not in the sense of "undefined behavior".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I thought inf/inf is considered undefined

You are using `gcc` most probably on a sane platform - your compiler is following [IEEE 754](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_754) the de-facto-standard floating point number format (also see [C11 Annex F](https://port70.net/%7Ensz/c/c11/n1570.html#F)). From [this pdf of that standard](https://irem.univ-reunion.fr/IMG/pdf/ieee-754-2008.pdf) we can read on page 37:

> 7.2 Invalid operation
>
> For operations producing results in floating-point format, the default result of an operation that signals the invalid operation exception **shall be** a quiet NaN that should provide some diagnostic information (see 6.2). These operations are:
>
> [....]
>
> e) division: division(0, 0) or division(∞, ∞)

The behavior is *defined* - it should be a quiet `NaN`.

The `-fsanitize=undefined` does not check for such cases, I think [documentation lists](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-10.2.0/gcc/Instrumentation-Options.html#index-fsanitize_003dundefined) what is detected.

Answer (score 1):

When part of the Standard characterizes something as Undefined Behavior, that means that as far as the Standard is concerned, implementations are generally free to define it or not as they see fit, presumably choosing whatever course of action would best serve their customers.  In the case of floating-point math, however, the Standard adds an additional requirement: all implementations which fail to treat certain floating-point operations as defined must refrain from pre-defining a macro `__STDC_IEC_559__`.  If an implementation pre-defines that macro, then it must treat as defined various operations that would not need to be defined on implementations that do not pre-define that macro.

Arguably, an undefined-behavior sanitizer should check whether a piece of code would only be executed on implementations that define `__STDC_IEC_559__`, and treat the aforementioned floating-point operations as defined only if they wouldn't occur on implementations that don't define that macro.  The only practical way of doing that, however, would be to build the program twice--once with the macro defined and once without--and validate the behavior of the two machine-code programs separately.